# Which servlet to use for generating Web Service in Spring

Tags: spring

I want to create Web Service (with Bottom to Top Principle) with Spring3.

Here I am confused with servlet which are required to declare in web.xml file.

I got two reference in Google which are using different servlets.

1> org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
  2> com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet

Can anyone suggest me which servlet to use for Spring Web Service ?

I am also facing problem with DI in the web service.

Here is my configuration sel-ws-config.xml  file  for the web-service....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
        xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"   
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
                            http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
                            ">

    <!-- FOR DEPENDENCY INJECTION -->                           
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eks.sel.web.service" />

    <!--SET THE SERVICE ANNOTATION DRIVEN -->
    <!-- <wss:annotation-driven/> -->                           

    <!--DECLARE WEB SERVICE BEAN DETAILs -->
    <wss:binding url="/authenticateUserService">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service  bean="#authenticateUserServiceBean" />                     
        </wss:service>      
    </wss:binding>


    <bean id="authenticateUserServiceBean" class="com.eks.sel.web.service.AuthenticateUserWS">
         <property name="userService">
            <ref bean="userService" />  
        </property> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And here is the code of web service bean ...

```
package com.eks.sel.web.service;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.eks.sel.controller.PageRenderConstant;
import com.eks.sel.service.IUserService;
import com.eks.sel.service.bean.SELUserVO;
import com.eks.sel.web.service.bean.AuthenticateUserReq;
import com.eks.sel.web.service.bean.AuthenticateUserRes;


@Service("authenticateUserWS")
@WebService
public class AuthenticateUserWS {


    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticateUserWS.class);

    /**
     * USER SERVICE DI : TO CALL AUTHENTICATE SERVICE
     */     

    /*@Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }*/


    public IUserService userService;

    @Inject
    public AuthenticateUserWS(IUserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    /**
     * WEB SERVICE USED TO AUTHENTICATE USER
     * @param req
     * @return
     */
    @WebMethod
    public AuthenticateUserRes authenticateUser(AuthenticateUserReq req){
        AuthenticateUserRes resp = null;
        try{
            if(this.userService==null){
                resp = new AuthenticateUserRes();
                resp.setRespCode(false);
                resp.setRespMessage("Injection Failed");
            }else if(req.getUserName()!=null && req.getPassword()!=null && req.getUserName().trim().length()>0
                    && req.getPassword().trim().length()>0){


                //CALL AUTHENTICATE SERVICE
                Map respMap = userService.checkUserCredential(req.getUserName(),req.getPassword());

                if(respMap!=null && respMap.get(PageRenderConstant.USER_VO)!=null){
                    SELUserVO userVo =(SELUserVO) respMap.get(PageRenderConstant.USER_VO);

                    //PREPARE RESPONSE WITH SUCCESS MESSAGE
                    resp = new AuthenticateUserRes();
                    resp.setRespCode(true);
                    resp.setRespMessage("VALID USER");
                    resp.setStoreCode(userVo.getSiteId());
                    resp.setStoreDesc(userVo.getSiteName());

                }else{
                    //PREPARE RESPONSE WITH ERROR
                    resp = new AuthenticateUserRes();
                    resp.setRespCode(false);
                    resp.setRespMessage("Invalid username OR Password");
                }
            }else{
                //PREPARE RESPONSE WITH ERROR
                resp = new AuthenticateUserRes();
                resp.setRespCode(false);
                resp.setRespMessage("Please provide valid username OR password");
            }           

        }catch(Exception ex){
            LOGGER.fatal("Exception generated in authenticate user web service : ",ex);

            //PREPARE RESPONSE WITH ERROR
            resp = new AuthenticateUserRes();
            resp.setRespCode(false);
            resp.setRespMessage("Error while validation : "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        return resp;
    }

}
```

And here is my web.xml file ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.eks.sel.listener.SELApplicationListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- SPRING HANDLER FOR DISPATCHING REQUEST -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>selsad</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/selsad/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>selsad</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>




    <!-- SERVLET FOR WEB SERVICE REQUEST PROCESSING -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <!-- <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class> -->
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class> -->        
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>        
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- PROJECT DISPLAY NAME -->
    <display-name>SELSAD</display-name>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And here is my root-context.xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources accessible to all other web components -->

    <!-- Property Config -->
    <import resource="property-config.xml"/>

    <!-- Database and Transaction Config -->
    <import resource="database-config.xml"/>

    <!-- SERVICE MODULE -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eks.sel.service" />

    <!-- DAO MODULE -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eks.sel.dao" />

    <!-- Mail Config -->
    <import resource="mail-config.xml"/>    

    <!-- Scheduler Config -->
    <import resource="scheduler-config.xml"/>

    <!-- Scheduler Config -->
    <import resource="scheduler-config-domain.xml"/>


    <!-- Web Service Config -->
    <import resource="sel-ws-config.xml"/>

</beans>
```

All the services including "**UserService**" are written under **com.eks.sel.service** package.
**sel-ws-config.xml** is my web-service configuration file which I have mentioned above.

And here is my userService bean which I am using in the web service to authenticate the user..

```
package com.eks.sel.service;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.math.RandomUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.eks.sel.controller.PageRenderConstant;
import com.eks.sel.dao.IConceptDAO;
import com.eks.sel.dao.ISiteDAO;
import com.eks.sel.dao.IUserDAO;
import com.eks.sel.model.Concept;
import com.eks.sel.model.Site;
import com.eks.sel.model.User;
import com.eks.sel.service.bean.SELUserVO;
import com.eks.sel.util.SELUtil;


@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    private IUserDAO userDAO;

    private ISiteDAO siteDAO;

    private IConceptDAO conceptDAO;

    /**
     * @param userDAO
     */
    @Inject
    public UserService(IUserDAO userDAO, IConceptDAO conceptDAO , ISiteDAO siteDAO) {       
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
        this.siteDAO = siteDAO;
        this.conceptDAO = conceptDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public Map checkUserCredential(String UserId, String password) {
        User user = this.userDAO.findById(UserId);
        Map userMap = new HashMap();        
        String result="INVALID";

        if(null!=user){
            if(null!=password && !"".equals(password) && password.equals(user.getPassword())){
                result="VALID";
                userMap.put(PageRenderConstant.USER_VO, getSelUserVo(user));
            }
        }
        userMap.put(PageRenderConstant.USER_LOGIN_MSG_KEY, result);
        return userMap;
    }



}
```

I am getting the following exception while using dependency injection...

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/sel-ws-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1045)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/sel-ws-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:343)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:513)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:333)
    at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.eks.sel.service.IUserService is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.eks.sel.service.IUserService
        at public com.eks.sel.service.IUserService com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService.arg0
        at com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService
com.eks.sel.service.IUserService does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.eks.sel.service.IUserService
        at public com.eks.sel.service.IUserService com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService.arg0
        at com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:158)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.eks.sel.service.IUserService is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.eks.sel.service.IUserService
        at public com.eks.sel.service.IUserService com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService.arg0
        at com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService
com.eks.sel.service.IUserService does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.eks.sel.service.IUserService
        at public com.eks.sel.service.IUserService com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService.arg0
        at com.eks.sel.web.service.jaxws.SetUserService
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1157)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:159)
    ... 68 more
```

I am not able to understand the problem. If it is generated bcoz of the servlet OR some other issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really posted your full configuration (web.xml for example) and/or what exactly your issue is. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "Bottom to Top" principle.

For web services design we usually talk about "**contract first**" or "**code first**" approaches, each being exactly what the name suggests:

- writing your contract (wsdl + xsd) first and then creating the code that conforms to that contract, or the other way around
- writing your code (services to be exposed as web services) first and then create (usually instead of writing just automatically generate) the contract out of it

Talking about Spring, there is a web service framework created by the Spring guys, called [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/) which heavily advocates the contract first approach. Another popular option is [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) which is a very mature framework developed by brilliant programmers from the Apache Foundation, with first-class Spring support. It's really up to you which one you choose. (Perhaps if you're a beginner CXF might be more natural for you using the code first approach, however CXF also supports contract first and for more complex scenarios that is the way to go definitely)

Step-by-step tutorial using Spring Web Services: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html

How-to using CXF: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here I am talking about code first service that we are calling as "Bottom to Top" principal. Here I have two problems.. Which servlet to use (I have commented in web.xml) for generating web service ?? And Second problem I am facing is dependency injecction. I am not able to inject Service Layer Bean to my web service class.

Comment: If you want to go code first, go with CXF, remove Spring WS from your project and follow the simple tutorial I posted.

For the other question, you have 2 spring context right, one root and one for the dispatcher servlet. The root being the one you defined at contextConfigLocation in web.xml. You can reference beans _from_ the root context in the dispatcher context, but not the other way around.

Comment: My simple hello world web service  is working fine with Spring-WS. So is there any specific advantage to go with CXF for "Code First Service" approach. Spring-WS is working fine. I am facing problem with dependency injection.

Comment: Where is your UserService bean defined? Which context?

Comment: UserService is defined in root-context.xml file. I have edited the question and added code of root-context.xml file.

Comment: do you have anywhere a component-scan directive for the package com.eks.sel.web.service?

Comment: yes... component-scan is declared in the root-context.xml file on the service package. I have added the exception details which I am getting while using the dependency injection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24110/discussion-between-gunjan-shah-and-abalogh)

Comment: Thanks for your interest and time. I have edited the answer and it works fine now..

Comment: We need to add @WebMethod(exclude = true) on the getter/setter of the userService bean. You can see this reference link : http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/spring-jax-ws-xxx-is-an-interface-and-jaxb-cant-handle-interfaces/ . It works fine after this annotation.